# Accessing array values using indexes in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm having some difficulties using `Twig`.

When I call `{{ dump(photos) }}` I get:

```
array (size=4)
    0 => string 'gjdh15,jpg,200,200' (length=18)
    1 => string 'gjdh13,jpg,200,200' (length=18)
    2 => string 'gjdh12,jpg,200,200' (length=18)
    3 => string 'gjdh10,jpg,200,200' (length=18)
```

When I call `{{ dump(photos[0]) }}` I get:

```
string 'gjdh15,jpg,200,200' (length=18)
```

**However** when I call `{{ dump(photos[1]) }}` I get an exception :

**Key "1" for array with keys "0" does not exist**

When it clearly does.

Is there a special way to access array values using an index in `Twig`? *(I can't use a loop).*

Comment: I've reproduced your problem and it works for me. Maybe problem occurs in different line?

Comment: Where does `photos` come from? Is it really an array, or something that behaves like one?

Comment: @Sparkup What do you get if `{{ dump(photos|keys) }}`? You can also try `{{ cycle(photos, 1) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a specific array value, you can use the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function, it works with both array and objects:

```
{{ attribute(photos, 1) }}
```

If the array key (or object attribute) may not exist, you can add the [default](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) filter to catch exceptions and print a fallback value.

```
{{ attribute(photos, 1)|default('No picture') }}
```